# Will creating reports on R using MySQL Database update my database on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, r

I use MySQL to store my data. To analyze the data I want to be able to generate monthly reports on R. So far I was able to connect to MySQL using `dbConnect` but I want to make sure that none of the tweaking I do affects the database I have in MySQL. Below is the code I used to import the database/table to R.

```
install.packages("RODBC")
library(RODBC)
Data<-dbConnect(drv, username="<insert username here>", password="<insert password here>", dbname ="<insert database name here>")
Table1 <- fetch(dbSendQuery(Data, "select * from Table"),-1)
```

Using the `fetch` function I am able to load the table into R but I want to make sure that I am not changing it on MySQL at the same time. Would applying any operations, adding columns etc affect the original database in MySQL?

Comment: SELECT query cannot alter data.

Comment: Right but what if I’m actually adding new columns and changing values? Would that change my data in MySQL too?

Comment: *what if I’m actually adding new columns and changing values?* You cannot do it by SELECT query. Show the code - how you will do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copy data from MySQL into `rstudio` (or your UI of choice), r pulls the data into memory.

When you then manipulate the data (by adding extra columns, for example), this happens entirely in memory & the source data (in your case a MySQL query, but it could just as easily have been from a csv file etc) is not modified in any way.

r is wonderful, but requires a slightly different way of thinking than SQL - hope you’re enjoying it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a little confused. I'm used to R but not MySQL. So by manipulating tables within R even after using the ```fetch()``` function it will still manipulate the original data in MySQL? Is there a way for me to just grab the data from MySQL and analyze it in R without changing anything in the MySQL database?

Comment: It'll manipulate the data within R itself, in memory. It won't mess with your MySQL tables